# Dynamics CRM month query

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

How can i query a specific month in Dynamics CRM.

```
            query = new QueryExpression("personnel") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("personnelid", "name", "surname", "birthdate") };

            query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.ThisMonth);
            result = Portal.Value.Connection.Value.Service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

This returns only if the birthdate's year is current year.

Answer (score 1):

`ThisMonth` operator means current month, so if you run the query today (2 January 2015) it will return only records with the date as January 2015.

As far as I know there isn't a way to query directly a specific month (I tried also with a LINQ late-bound query but due to the CRM LINQ provider a query like `where ((DateTime)c["birthdate"]).Month == 1` doesn't work).

Comment: How can i do this to my result?

Comment: if you are OnPremise you can use the FilteredViews, otherwise you can create an integer field to hold the month and keep the value consistent with the birthdate

Answer (score 1):

you could use a range to specify the month you want

```
 query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, new DateTime(2016,5,1));
 query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, new DateTime(2016, 5, 31,23,59,59));
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hello, if you are just trying to get these information for a report o for general knowledge could use a PowerBI Report, if you need it for an specific business requirement you will need to extrac the Date parts into different attributes and apply the query to it, the SDK or FetchXml won't allow datepart queries

Answer (score 1):

Diaz was giving a good idea; instead of using specific dates, you might want to replace them with dynamics values.

E.g. to query the current month:

```
 query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, DateTime.Now);
 query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1-DateTime.Today.Day));
```

Answer (score 0):

We have faced exactly the same requirement & we found the below solution to help us

1. create a new field in CRM  called "Upcoming birthday"
2. create a custom workflow/plugin/batch application to calculate the next birthday (code for the same is here http://www.resultondemand.nl/support/sdk/1cff83b0-1f7b-4ddb-a2af-b85f9f785529.htm
3. Use the same thismonth filter to get the results.

This method has its own drawback as below

1. Plugin needs a triggering event (which you need to decide according to your business).
2. Custom workflow - This is most suggested as you can retreive all the contacts which have birthday in last year same day and update it. You can set the custom workflow to timeout and repeat everyday.
3. Batch Application - This method needs the batch application to be hosted in server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the month. You are limited by the capacity of FetchXML.

Try doing the query using the Advanced Find. In your case I think you could use a combination of two conditions. "Older than X months" and "Next X Months". Then, you can find the X using `Today().Months`.

Answer (score 0):

Query Expression is too complicated. Instead, use fetch xml. You can filter by years, months or fiscal years. Like in the advanced find.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334216.aspx

Comment: You forgot to notice your earlier answer in this post. Improvise the old answer :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42537681/7920473

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
  query.Criteria.AddCondition("birthdate", ConditionOperator.Equal,DateTime) ;
```